# plotting a pdf together with a histogram using plotnine in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotnine

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *
```

gd_sp_tmp = pd.DataFrame({
        'variable': {0: 'var1', 1: 'var1', 2: 'var1', 3: 'var1', 4: 'var1', 5: 'var1', 6: 'var1', 7: 'var1', 8: 'var1',
                     9: 'var1', 10: 'var1', 11: 'var1', 12: 'var1', 13: 'var1', 14: 'var1', 15: 'var1', 16: 'var1',
                     17: 'var1', 18: 'var1', 19: 'var1', 20: 'var1', 21: 'var1', 22: 'var1', 23: 'var1', 24: 'var1',
                     25: 'var1', 26: 'var1', 27: 'var1', 28: 'var1', 29: 'var1', 30: 'var1', 31: 'var1', 32: 'var1',
                     33: 'var1', 34: 'var1', 35: 'var1', 36: 'var1', 37: 'var1', 38: 'var1', 39: 'var1', 40: 'var1',
                     41: 'var1', 42: 'var1', 43: 'var1', 44: 'var1', 45: 'var1', 46: 'var1', 47: 'var1', 48: 'var1',
                     49: 'var1', 50: 'var2', 51: 'var2', 52: 'var2', 53: 'var2', 54: 'var2', 55: 'var2', 56: 'var2',
                     57: 'var2', 58: 'var2', 59: 'var2', 60: 'var2', 61: 'var2', 62: 'var2', 63: 'var2', 64: 'var2',
                     65: 'var2', 66: 'var2', 67: 'var2', 68: 'var2', 69: 'var2', 70: 'var2', 71: 'var2', 72: 'var2',
                     73: 'var2', 74: 'var2', 75: 'var2', 76: 'var2', 77: 'var2', 78: 'var2', 79: 'var2', 80: 'var2',
                     81: 'var2', 82: 'var2', 83: 'var2', 84: 'var2', 85: 'var2', 86: 'var2', 87: 'var2', 88: 'var2',
                     89: 'var2', 90: 'var2', 91: 'var2', 92: 'var2', 93: 'var2', 94: 'var2', 95: 'var2', 96: 'var2',
                     97: 'var2', 98: 'var2', 99: 'var2'},
        'value': {0: 0.6058597809345508, 1: 0.5793863580299581, 2: 0.8464980992038321, 3: 0.24855227431181698,
                  4: 1.8852877490212698, 5: 0.4234171954404873, 6: 0.3435477323074209, 7: 3.358464370031963,
                  8: 0.5253401196517882, 9: 2.358632857360592, 10: 0.15960003602748035, 11: 0.2882705893127418,
                  12: 1.0995070639266127, 13: 0.3492611123700738, 14: 0.656410247866536, 15: 1.7926397942332677,
                  16: 0.2809984468410994, 17: 2.146319743864339, 18: 1.6912849075574694, 19: 1.233812138850312,
                  20: 0.21044290817060624, 21: 0.7130666643073327, 22: 0.521102906290718, 23: 0.8191663841868542,
                  24: 0.20231016020355008, 25: 1.542239677553837, 26: 0.07752167395995535, 27: 0.07661799644296931,
                  28: 0.13728522388491152, 29: 1.4268916808352554, 30: 1.2219293081314697, 31: 1.089318287649674,
                  32: 0.5889304040483466, 33: 3.871173476569569, 34: 0.2571045126240674, 35: 0.27332795371650104,
                  36: 1.2121464473427577, 37: 2.0229834870080117, 38: 0.5538327169626888, 39: 0.3354345395246616,
                  40: 0.39169801317212116, 41: 1.0415690828271393, 42: 0.9584774133158281, 43: 0.13738535777663943,
                  44: 1.874003757544322, 45: 1.7852374480589213, 46: 1.6370785639935181, 47: 0.8738310745465996,
                  48: 0.4777945179886022, 49: 0.7289840311727211, 50: 0.7922955784270402, 51: 0.9104711980757718,
                  52: 1.5561240516907253, 53: 0.3303774972464219, 54: 2.110632552079527, 55: 0.49383897345236455,
                  56: 0.5328351983603986, 57: 1.101045960316634, 58: 0.6511245820579645, 59: 1.1162218482680217,
                  60: 1.1528904383298124, 61: 0.34335972679097204, 62: 1.018800464369946, 63: 0.5416579415333236,
                  64: 1.214519609326636, 65: 0.23298089233642374, 66: 1.2353245009353024, 67: 0.41366066807689983,
                  68: 0.3922217060873213, 69: 0.47724897903224234, 70: 1.2372675447604105, 71: 0.860009005949974,
                  72: 0.975115860544153, 73: 0.34103695692671854, 74: 3.715667756746576, 75: 0.8245813402150265,
                  76: 1.0146261204408322, 77: 1.429071625166872, 78: 1.1575801036803262, 79: 0.8892865356335216,
                  80: 1.4682387127243648, 81: 0.2790711201452777, 82: 0.21458250943662763, 83: 1.626193381231688,
                  84: 0.7862776167644395, 85: 0.8063680366888433, 86: 2.1349518016852866, 87: 0.16790682625128348,
                  88: 2.6898324320852316, 89: 3.1017929388719687, 90: 2.2161796611039484, 91: 0.27323366047568587,
                  92: 0.9876405202465337, 93: 0.5878226010690092, 94: 0.975411448085179, 95: 0.7933992437453187,
                  96: 1.3443593604932238, 97: 1.5392784611233619, 98: 1.1729165101630914, 99: 0.7643250100538129}})

I create the following histograms

```
plot_posterior_test = ggplot(data=gd_sp_tmp) + \
                           geom_histogram(aes(x='value', y='stat(density)')) + \
                           facet_wrap('~variable')
```

I would like to add on this plot, the pdf of a `lognormal` distribution with `scale = 0.8` and `location = -0.5` in **all** graphs. Any ideas how could I do that using `plotnine` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `stat_function`. For example, given your prior code, try this

```
import scipy.stats as stats

(ggplot(data=gd_sp_tmp)
 + geom_histogram(aes(x='value'))
 + stat_function(fun=stats.lognorm.pdf, args=dict(s=.95, loc=0.8, scale=-0.5))
 + facet_wrap('~variable')
)
```

It is up to you to make sure that the parameters make sense, otherwise they will compute to `NaN` values

Comment: Thank you. It works that way. Now the problem is that the bars from the histogram are too high (and therefore the pdf is not very clear). Is it possible to make the `y-axis` as a percentage (so that it becomes lower), so that the shape of the pdf is more clear ? And if so, how ?

Comment: @quant, For the histogram you should plot the density so that area under each plot is one. `geom_histogram(aes(x='value', y='stat(density)'))`. See the [documentation](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.stats.stat_bin.html) for more.

Comment: This is what I am plotting